# How to get file path without quotes in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to get only the real path of the file selected without quotes and without the file extension

```
def newCall(self):
        global rfile
        rfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Sélectionner une vidéo", "", "Video Files (*.mp4)")
        self.lineEntry.setText(str(rfile))
        print('Selected:', rfile)
```

When I run the code I will get this

```
Selected: ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/segmentation/comfort.mp4', 'Video Files (*.mp4)')
```

I need only this path

```
C:/Users/user/Desktop/segmentation/comfort.mp4
```

Comment: change `rfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Sélectionner une vidéo", "", "Video Files (*.mp4)")`   to `rfile, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Sélectionner une vidéo", "", "Video Files (*.mp4)")`

Answer (score 0):

Select the first element in `rfile` (which is a tuple holding both the selected path and the used file type filter), and replace `'` with an empty string:

```
file_path = rfile[0].replace("'", "")
```